Best strategy for verification of constitutive tangent for hyperelastic material
This is a theoretical/coding question.
Let's say I have a strain energy density function W = W(I1,I2) + W(I3). I am using material models such as Neo-Hookean or 2nd order Mooney-Rivlin.
The second PK stress is then defined as
S_{ij} = ∂W/∂E_{ij}
and the constitutive tensor
C_{ijkl} = ∂/∂E_{kl}(∂W/∂E_{ij}).
If I want to verify that I'm deriving the correct analytical constitutive and stress tensor equations, what's the best way without using a commercial code?
The strategy I chose was using a MATLAB/Python code to simulate uni-axial tension the following way:
lambda = [1.0 -> 1.5] (100x1 array of applied stretch to material)
For i in lambda:
Define deformation gradient F
Get right cauchy green tensor C and Lagrange strain E
Get invariants I1, I2 and I3 of C
Get S^(analytical)_{ij}=∂W/∂E_{ij} by plugging in invariants
Get stress from product of constitutive tensor and lagrange strain, S^(tangent)_{ij} = C_{ijkl}E_{kl}

To compare the stress, I can use a generic analytical equation for uniaxial stress, for e.g., in this link: (Section 8.7 and 8.8)
https://www.brown.edu/Departments/Engineering/Courses/En221/Notes/Elasticity/Elasticity.htm
To get the correct constitutive tensor is where I am getting stuck at.
Should I just compare the two stresses, S^(analytical){ij} and S^(tangent){ij}(either through a plot or through a point wise error), besides the usual symmetry checks?
Is this way correct? Essentially, is S_{ij} = C_{ijkl}E_{kl} valid at all points in the range of stretches for hyper-elastic materials?
Thank you!
